# What species is the smallest bird?

Tags: ornithology

What species is the smallest living bird in the world? What circumstances limit the bird size from the bottom?

Comment: There are definitely two questions here, and the question in the title and first part of the body should really be flagged for closure - it's easily googled - but the second is interesting and on-scope. Do you think you could edit it to the second part only?

Comment: this paper may interest you. minimum size may be related to maintaining their body temprature. https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/282753

Comment: Related posts: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21541, https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/66659

Answer (score 8):

The smallest bird in the world is the [bee hummingbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee_hummingbird).

I think the minimum size is only limited by the size of organs. I mean that certain organs need to have a minimum size to maintain their function in the organism.

Comment: It is unclear to me how the "Wall effect" that you link under "organism" is relevant to your point. Is that an error?

Comment: The answered was probably thinking of something more like this, http://www.mrothery.co.uk/exchange/allkeynotesas.htm, but that is more of a limit on maximum size rather than minimum size.

Comment: @vkehayas yeah it is not much related to this topic. I quite misuse that it.

Comment: @L.Diago maybe update the link to reference [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee_hummingbird) instead, which not only gives the facts listed in your link, but also has pictures of them?

Comment: A better link: [Bee Hummingbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee_hummingbird).

Comment: I understand guys but that link was from guinessworldrecords you know. I  thought that it will fit better with the smallest bird in the world. :)

Comment: A complete answer should at least mention [Kleiber's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleiber's_law).

Comment: I dont know but it doesnt fit to my answer.